# Automatic login script for a website on windows machine?

Tags: javascript, windows, vbscript, autologin, webautomation

I saw some guy had a file (I guess a batch file). On clicking of the batch file he was able to log in to multiple sites. (Perhaps it was done using VB.)

I looked for such a script on Google but didn't find anything useful.

I know a bit of C++ and UNIX (also some HTML and JavaScript). I don't know if it can be done on a windows machine using these languages, but even if it could be done I think it would be difficult compared to VB or C## or some other high level languages.

I learned how to open multiple sites using basic windows batch commands enclosed in a batch file like:

```
start http://www.gmail.com
start http://stackoverflow.com
```

But still I can't figure out how actually clicking on the batch file would help me to log in to the sites without even typing the username and password.

Do I need to start learning Visual Basic, .NET, or windows batch programming to do this?

One more thing: can I also use it to log in to remote desktops?

Comment: Please edit my tags so that the concerned people can see it I am totally unaware of the area to which this question should belongi.e C++,windows,website,vbscript,unix,javascript,htmletc

Comment: I wanted this because its very annoying login into a set of sites everyday and filling the username and passwords everytime....Instaed if something can be done to automate it would be good

Answer (score 15):

From the term "automatic login" I suppose security (password protection) is not of key importance here.

The guidelines for solution could be to use a JavaScript bookmark (idea borrowed form a nice game published on [M&M's DK site](http://www.m-ms.dk/spaceheroes/)).

The idea is to create a javascript file and store it locally. It should do the login data entering depending on current site address. Just an example using jQuery:

```
// dont forget to include jQuery code
// preferably with .noConflict() in order not to break the site scripts
if (window.location.indexOf("mail.google.com") > -1) {
    // Lets login to Gmail
    jQuery("#Email").val("youremail@gmail.com");
    jQuery("#Passwd").val("superSecretPassowrd");
    jQuery("#gaia_loginform").submit();
}
```

Now save this as say `login.js`

Then create a bookmark (in any browser) with this (as an) url:

```
javascript:document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///path/to/login.js'></script>");
```

Now when you go to Gmail and click this bookmark you will get automatically logged in by your script.

Multiply the code blocks in your script, to add more sites in the similar manner. You could even combine it with `window.open(...)` functionality to open more sites, but that may get the script inclusion more complicated.

Note: This only illustrates an idea and needs lots of further work, it's not a complete solution.

Comment: Have you tried the link I proposed? They use the same principle (maybe I'm wrong with `document.write` part, they use a more suitable `document.createElement`), and it works. And as I said, this is not a complete solution - this is just a skeleton to give you an idea how it could be done.

Comment: I get an error of <script> source URI is not allowed in this document: Any idea why it is?

Comment: One can also run this in Tampermonkey/Greesemonkey

Comment: @SanjuRao - possibly browser security standards improved since 2011. This is kind of a hack (basically a XSS), so I'm not surprised that this may be disallowed by now

Comment: Cool. Is there any other way to implement this?  Its very annoying for me to keep typing the user credentials every time for my development.

Comment: I'd recommend using some password manager with a browser plugin  - https://www.lastpass.com/ is my favourite. It does the login form autofill but also you can securely store your actual passwords across browsers and even devices

Answer (score 9):

The code below does just that.  The below is a working example to log into a game.  I made a similar file to log in into Yahoo and a kurzweilai.net forum.

Just copy the login form from any webpage's source code. Add value= "your user name" and value = "your password".  Normally the **-input-** elements in the source code do not have the value attribute, and sometime, you will see something like that:  **value=""**

Save the file as a html on a local machine double click it, or make a bat/cmd file to  launch and close them as required.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

    <html>
    <title>Ikariam Autologin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post"    action="http://s666.en.ikariam.com/index.php?action=loginAvatar&function=login">
    <select name="uni_url" id="logServer" class="validate[required]">
    <option  class=""  value="s666.en.ikariam.com" fbUrl=""  cookieName=""  >
            Test_en
    </option>
    </select>
    <input id="loginName" name="name" type="text" value="PlayersName" class="" />
    <input id="loginPassword" name="password" type="password" value="examplepassword" class="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="loginKid" name="kid" value=""/>
                        </form>
  <script>document.loginForm.submit();</script>       
  </body></html>
```

Note that -script- is just -script-. I found there is no need to specify that is is JavaScript. It works anyway. I also found out that a bare-bones version that contains just two input filds: userName and password also work. But I left a hidded input field etc. just in case.  Yahoo mail has a lot of hidden fields. Some are to do with password encryption, and it counts login attempts.

Security warnings and other staff, like Mark of the Web to make it work smoothly in IE are explained here:

http://happy-snail.webs.com/autologinintogames.htm

Comment: You may have to modify the `href=` and `action=` fields to include the full URL.  At least the `action=` of the `<form>` has to have the full URL if you are hosting the login form locally.

Answer (score 2):

I used @qwertyjones's answer to automate logging into Oracle Agile with a public password.

I saved the login page as `index.html`, edited all the `href=` and `action=` fields to have the full URL to the Agile server.

The key `<form>` line needed to change from

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="MainForm" method="POST"
 action="j_security_check" 
 onsubmit="return false;" target="_top">
```

to

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="MainForm" method="POST"
 action="http://my.company.com:7001/Agile/default/j_security_check"   
 onsubmit="return false;" target="_top">
```

I also added this snippet to the end of the `<body>`

```
<script>
function checkCookiesEnabled(){ return true; }
document.MainForm.j_username.value = "joeuser";
document.MainForm.j_password.value = "abcdef";
submitLoginForm();
</script>
```

I had to disable the cookie check by redefining the function that did the check, because I was hosting this from XAMPP and I didn't want to deal with it. The `submitLoginForm()` call was inspired by inspecting the `keyPressEvent()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Autohotkey`, download it from: http://ahkscript.org/download/

After the installation, if you want to open Gmail website when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>, you can do something like this:

```
!g::
Run www.gmail.com 
return
```

Further reference: [Hotkeys (Mouse, Joystick and Keyboard Shortcuts)](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Well, its true that we can use Vb Script for what you intended to do.
We can open an application through the code like Internet Explorer. We can navigate to site you intend for. Later we can check the element names of Text Boxes which require username and password; can set then and then Login. It works fine all of using code.

No manual interaction with the website. And eventually you will end up signing in by just double clicking the file.

To get you started :

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Call objIE.Navigate("https://gmail.com")
```

This will open an instance of internet explore and navigate to gmail.
Rest you can learn and apply.