# How can I manipulate DOM with Java?

Tags: java, dom, dom-manipulation

Is there any way I can get a DOM element and manipulate it so I can put my username and password in order to login automatically, when starting the application? For now, I've used Robot in order to let the computer pass in my login information and login automatically, but I need a better method. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main
{
private static String OS                = null;
private static Integer CTRL             = null;

private static String username          = "u1240430";
private static String password          = "123123";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    OS = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if( OS.equalsIgnoreCase("MAC OS X") ){
        CTRL = KeyEvent.VK_META;
    }else{
        CTRL = KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL;
    }


    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("https://awebsite.something/login.php").toURI());
        startWithLogin();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static void startWithLogin() {
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();

        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(username);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, null);

        r.delay(1500);

        r.keyPress(CTRL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(CTRL);

        r.delay(100);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

        r.delay(100);

        selection = new StringSelection(password);
        clipboard.setContents(selection, null);

        r.delay(100);

        r.keyPress(CTRL);
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        r.keyRelease(CTRL);

        r.delay(100);

        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you NEED to do this in java? Why not just make a bookmarklet in JS?

Comment: I would like to create an app where I can add buttons and go to websites to login automatically. I like Java, that's why I want to try it in Java. Do you have any java/javascript examples?

Comment: If this is only for yourself, youre probably better off writing a small browser plugin or building a couple of bookmarkets. Heres a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine)

Comment: ( The short answer to your question would probably "No" but that doesn't really help you, thats why im suggesting using the browser's tools. )

Comment: Thanks man, I will make a small app to manipulate Javascript with Java and with Javascript any DOM.