# Automatically select a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to figure out how to create a page that I can pass through to the rest of my scripts that will automatically login.

The site I need to log in to doesn't allow the username and password in the URL so I've been trying to use jquery and a modded HTML file of the login page (with all their scripts but the rest stripped out).
I've been looking at he following examples:
[Automatic login script for a website on windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine) and https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33592/automatically-clicking-button-on-a-specific-webpage

The issue is the page loads, the modded default value shows up, but it never does anything else. If I click the button it works fine, so I'm assuming the click is not working (even though I have put the script outside the HTML and called it, put it at the end of the HTML, and put at the beginning of the HTML).

This is code for the button in the HTML:

```
<p class="tdBtn"><input type="submit" name="loginSubmit" tabindex="3" value="Login" class="formBtn" id="loginSubmit">
```

And this is the jquery I've put in:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript">/script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
       $("a.loginSubmit").trigger('click');
    },10);
   });
</script>
```

But nothing is happening.

Because this is part of an automation script, I don't want to have to use the bookmark method.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have an idea for a simpler solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$("#loginSubmit").trigger('click');
```

since you've used `<input>` element not `<a>` as well as there's no class `loginSubmit`, you only have `input` with id `loginSubmit`, or if you want to target it by `name` attribute then use:

```
$("input[name=loginSubmit]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick... I tried all the suggestions here and none of them were working until I realized I missed the < to close the first script...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript">/script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
       $("#loginSubmit").trigger('click');
    },10);
   });
</script>
```

please see it http://jsfiddle.net/g8ntp/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

$("#loginSubmit").trigger('click');
since you've used  element not  as well as there's no class loginSubmit, you only have input with id loginSubmit, or if you want to target it by name attribute then use:

$("input[name=loginSubmit]").trigger('click');

plzz ignore the syntax...i m new to it