# auto login userscript using geasemonkey or tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I was wondering if there is a possibility of writing an autologin script using tampermonkey or using add-on like greasemonkey to write an auto-login userscript for http://www.kongregate.com/games/jiggmin/platform-racing-2

Comment: You could try writing a VB program. It'd be super sketchy, though.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Will someone here just hand you a complete solution without any visible effort on your part? No. Will they help you fix issues you are having implementing your own solution? Certainly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The system is flash-based, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10947293/1470607) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean logging into the flash game, no sorry. If you mean logging into the website, yes ([Logging into website with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine)). But what you can do is try other kinds of software to do this, like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), where you can log in by pressing a single button.